# LINQ-SQL having concurrency issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

The way I use LINQ SQL is with 1 global datacontext.

I am having problems though. I have one page I go to that grabs all Cases in the db and copies data from the result IEnumerable.

Then, when I navigate to go do some updates on those cases, it fails.

Is there anything I can do to fix concurrency issues or these types of general issues while still only using 1 data context per user session? Would it help maybe I used a new data context every page load or something?

Thanks

Comment: "it fails" is not a very descriptive explanation of the error

Comment: It is recommended to perform atomic operations instantiating datacontext when needed and disposing of it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 1 global datacontext in ASP.NET; you need one global context per HTTP request, because you'll deal with issues like you mentioned.  LINQ to SQL tracks objects changes in a graph, and a static context will contain instances of objects disposed in a previous HTTP request.  Plus, overtime, it would get bloated and take up a lot of memory.  The approach is to store an instance of it in `HttpContext.Current.Items`.